# process interrupted: signal: killed

Tags: go, goland

I installed a utility called watcher.

https://github.com/canthefason/go-watcher

It works as expected using VS code.

But when I tried to use it in Goland (from Jetbrains) I get the following:

```
watcher main.go --port 8080
2020/03/04 14:10:42 build started
Building ....
2020/03/04 14:10:43 build completed
Running ...
2020/03/04 14:10:43 process interrupted: signal: killed
```

Needless to say `go run main.go --port 8080` works.

I use a MAC Catalina.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running this from GoLand and how can I replicate this?

Comment: I just call watcher main.go --port 8080
To replicate it you need to install it from the instructions in https://github.com/canthefason/go-watcher
Then make sure your path is set.
Finally call: watcher main.go --port 8080

Comment: So, you run this in a separate terminal and then use the editor to work on the files. When you finish, you expect the tool to recompile the application. Is that correct? The application is not configured using File Watchers or External Tools from GoLand, correct?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like [an error from cmd.Wait()](https://github.com/canthefason/go-watcher/blob/59980168ee35c24b8dc3c3bb3dec2ed749fa5c44/run.go#L49)

```
if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("process interrupted: %s \n", err)
    ...
```

[A similar report](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-build-exits-with-signal-killed/513) was the OS killing the process because it was out of memory (OOM), and dmesg might have logged the error.